JFrog Artifactory What is the best way to find latest version in repo
I'm building a PowerShell script to install the JF cli tool. However, I would like to check to see what the latest version of the tool is then compare that to my installed version. However, I'm not sure what is the best way to gather the latest jf version from  https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/jfrog-cli/v2-jf/ or from https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli/releases
Right now I'm just running the iwr https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/jfrog-cli/v2-jf/[RELEASE]/jfrog-cli-windows-amd64/jf.exe -OutFile $env:SYSTEMROOT\system32\jf.exe command which will always download and overwrite the file, if it's not needed I would prefer to skip this.
any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

I found that GitHub has some nice APIs that I can use, such as https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/releases?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-the-latest-release--parameters
for powershell I just use (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://api.github.com/repos/jfrog/jfrog-cli/releases/latest).Content | ConvertFrom-Json).name -replace '^v' to get the version needed.
